# Can I target a :before or :after pseudo-element with a sibling combinator?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Is there a reason why this CSS doesn't work?

http://jsfiddle.net/6v5BZ/

```css
a[href^="http"]:after {
    content:"";
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    display:inline-block;
    background-color:red;
}

a[href^="http"] img ~ :after {
    display:none;
}
```

.. on this HTML?

```html
<a href="http://google.com">Test</a>
<a href="http://google.com">
    <img src="https://www.google.com/logos/classicplus.png">
</a>
```

The idea is to have a pseudo-element on matching anchor tags. But I do not want it to apply to anchor tags that wrap an image. And since I can't target anchors using something like `a < img`, I figured the maybe I could target the :after pseudo-element by finding an image that it's a sibling of.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: CSS2 syntax: `:after`, CSS3 syntax: `::after`.

Comment: The pseudo-element syntax is irrelevant. Either will work.

Comment: oh how i also wanted this..

Comment: I got here googling if a pseudo element can be targeted via media query. I think it cannot

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't target :after since it's content is not rendered in the DOM and it does not manipulate it - for this to work the DOM would have to be re-rendered and CSS can't manipulate it like this.

Check the specification for detailed understanding: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#propdef-content

> Generated content does not alter the document tree. In particular, it
>   is not fed back to the document language processor (e.g., for
>   reparsing).

I suggest you use JavaScript to do the job for you.

Comment: This is correct regarding pseudo-elements and the DOM. Consequently, it also has to do with how pseudo-element selectors are processed. See my answer.

Answer (score 22):

You cannot use a combinator to target a pseudo-element relative to elements other than its generating element.

This is because they're *pseudo-elements*, not actual elements, and combinators only work by establishing relationships between actual elements. A pseudo-element, on the other hand, can only be applied to the subject of a selector (the rightmost compound selector), and this happens only after matching is processed on the real elements. In other words, matching is done first as though the pseudo-element wasn't there, then the pseudo-element, if it's indicated within the selector, is applied to each match.

In your code, the following selector:

```
a[href^="http"] img ~ :after
```

Does not actually look for an `:after` pseudo-element that comes after an `img` within the `a`, even though it appears that way as both are rendered as children of the `a` element.

It can be rewritten into the following:

```
a[href^="http"] img ~ *:after
```

Notice the `*` selector, which is implied. Similarly to how you can omit `*` before any other simple selectors for it to be implied, omitting `*` from a pseudo-element also makes it implied to be there. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#universal-selector) for details.

Now, even though it appears `*:after` should still match `a:after` (since `a` would match `*`), it still doesn't work that way. If you remove the `:after` pseudo-element from the selector:

```
a[href^="http"] img ~ *
```

You'll notice that the meaning of the selector changes entirely:

> Select any element
>   that appears as a following sibling of an `img`
>   that is a descendant of an `a` (whose `href` starts with "http").

Since the `img` is the last child of the `a` element in your HTML, there are no following siblings to match, and therefore no `:after` pseudo-elements can be generated.

In the case of a `:before` or `:after` pseudo-element, one might think of matching the pseudo-element's generating element relative to the pseudo-element's "sibling", but as the OP has correctly pointed out, [there is no parent selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), so they're out of luck there, too.

Comment: Would targeting pseudo elements work using the `:last-child` pseudo-class also not work because as you mentioned, selectors, then pseudo-elements?

Comment: @Jacob Schneider: That's correct. Pseudo-elements are neither the first, last, nor indeed nth child of their parent. Those structural pseudo-classes do not match pseudo-elements.

Comment: I, too, wondered about something similar. More specifically, if you could use `input:checked` to target `::after` in my case `input[type="checkbox"]:checked + :after`. Alas, it doesn't work... Though I will ask, has there been any change to this question/answer, as it's relatively old?

Comment: @Beaniie: No, there hasn't.