# Access child element relative to generated content

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Let's say I have HTML like so:

```
<div class="foo">
    <div>Stuff</div>
</div>
```

And some CSS like so:

```
.foo > div { display: none; }
.foo:after { /* rules */ }
```

I would like to be able to do something like

```
.foo:after:hover > div { display: block; }
```

to have the user hover over the generated content element and show the child `div`. Does anyone know how to do this? My attempts so far have been fruitless. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question seems to be the opposite of [Can I target a :before or :after pseudo-element with a sibling combinator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735267/can-i-target-an-after-pseudo-element-with-a-sibling-combinator/7748876#7748876)

In your case, you cannot apply pseudo-classes to pseudo-elements. This also means you cannot choose to apply styles only when a pseudo-element is on `:hover` *but not its generating element*. Instead, you can only select a pseudo-element depending on the pseudo-class states of its generating element, and only when this generating element is the subject of the selector.

Also, as mentioned, pseudo-elements are not part of the DOM. Therefore, similarly to how you cannot reach pseudo-elements relatively to real children within the same generating element as shown in my answer to the above question (explanation in the above link):

```
a[href^="http"] img ~ :after
```

You cannot select real elements relatively to pseudo-elements within the same generating element:

```
.foo:after > div
```

So to sum up, the reason why the following selector won't work:

```
.foo:after:hover > div
```

Is twofold:

1. Pseudo-elements cannot have pseudo-class states, making `:after:hover` invalid.
2. The subject of the selector here is not `.foo`, but `div`, so `:after` cannot apply to `.foo`. Consequently, attempting to select a real element as the subject of a selector after applying a pseudo-element to another selector doesn't make sense.

If you really must not display your `div` on `.foo:hover`, but on another child element, then your only way around this without using JavaScript is to make another real element under `.foo` that comes *before* the `div` (not *after*):

```
<div class="foo">
    <div></div>
    <div>Stuff</div>
</div>
```

This is because [there is no previous sibling selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector); the adjacent sibling selector, which you can use in place of `:after >` is only for selecting the *next* sibling:

```
.foo > div:first-child + div { display: none; }
.foo > div:first-child { /* rules */ }
.foo > div:first-child:hover + div { display: block; }
```

Comment: Thank you for this very thorough, correct answer. I had arrived at this conclusion independently yesterday, but you have filled in a lot of blanks as to why this is the case. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't interact with generated content, as it's not present in the DOM (it can be *accessed*, but, so far at least, it's read-only); the only option you have is to use `:hover` on `.foo` itself:

```
.foo:hover > div { }
```

You could, of course, style the generated content differently on `:hover`:

```
.foo:hover::after { }
```

But, I suspect, that probably isn't any part of what you want to do.

Also, your selector as written: `.foo:after:hover > div` I think, would try to style the `div` child of the generated content; which it can't have.

Comment: i figured this was the case, but was hoping it wasn't. thanks

Comment: I suspect that, as generated content matures, it'll become present in, and accessible via, the DOM in a read *and* write capacity (and to CSS too), but, sadly, not yet. Sorry I couldn't bring better news =/

Comment: I've added an answer with an explanation as to why all this doesn't work, as well as an HTML/CSS-based workaround. (I also stole a bit of your use of words just for kicks.)

Answer (score 0):

You were close. Just ditch the :after portion.

http://jsfiddle.net/QERPq/

UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/QERPq/2/
Basically, this says that when you hover over this item, to select the next item (* = catchall) and display it.

Comment: i don't want to ditch the `:after`. that's the part i want to hover over.

Comment: again, i want the `:after` portion. your fiddle doesn't have any generated content :\

Comment: Oh, I get the feeling I missed it again. You want to hover over the "morecontent" area, and display the div inside .foo?

Comment: Assuming morecontent is generated.

Comment: i want to hover over the generated content and have the sibling div of the generated content's parent to appear.

Comment: I still don't think I'm entirely understanding what you're asking, but I generated content, with a child, and hovering over that child displays the normal content. http://jsfiddle.net/QERPq/3/

Comment: @Torr3nt: That is not the CSS definition of "generated content"; that is just using JS to add new elements to the DOM, which has nothing to do with CSS. See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) to understand what CSS generated content is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/QERPq/4/.

It may or may not be what you are after.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="foo">pre-hover stuff</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.foo > div {
    display: none;
    font-size: 200px;
}
.foo:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background: yellow;
}
.foo:hover:after {
    display: block;
    content: 'Stuff';
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: i'm looking to hover over the `:after` and have it show the parent's child div

Comment: @Jason See the updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/QERPq/5/). If either the main `div` or the generated content are hovered over, the child `div` will display.

Comment: ok, but i don't want the div to show when the parent is hovered, just the generated content.

Comment: @Jason Well that makes it very tricky. Does it *have* to be generated content?

Comment: @Jason - Okay, I solved it. There has to be an overlay `div` - see another updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QERPq/7/.