# CSS: Does the plus sign work with pseudo elements?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

For markup similar to this:

```
<div>
    <p>hello world</p>
</div>
<div>
    <h4>hello world</h4>
</div>
```

Can you do something like this in CSS:

```
div:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   border-bottom: 2px solid red;
}
p + div:after {
   content: "";
   display: block;
   border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}
```

...meaning to say "Give all :after pseudo elements immediately following a `<p>` a blue border. Give all others a red border".

This [doesn't seem to work](http://jsfiddle.net/medtg77e/). I realize this is because the + sign is applying to the 'div' selector, not the 'div:after' selector as a whole.  But is there another way to target these in CSS (without adding a new class specific to these instances and without manipulating the DOM)?

Comment: That's not what `+` means.

Comment: It really depends on what you are actually trying to do....essentially, at the moment, you need a parent selector...and there isn't one.

Comment: *Give all `:after` pseudo elements immediately following a <p> a blue border. Give all others a red border.* What is it exactly you want to target with the `::after`? You can't target a pseudo-element. A pseudo-element is added to a selector that has matched an element.

Comment: @Juhana: That much is pointed out in the question.

Comment: @BoltClock *"I realize this is because the + sign is applying to the 'div' selector, not the 'div:after' selector as a whole"* --> I interpret this so that the OP thinks `p + div` would target the second div, which it doesn't.

Comment: @Juhana: What I think is that the OP is saying it's targeting a div element that he knows doesn't exist - which is *represented* by the 'div' type selector. But it can be interpreted both ways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, what Michael_B said:

> You can't target a pseudo-element. A pseudo-element is added to a selector that has matched an element.

"Target" is a vague term, but the second sentence is on point here. Combinators only work with elements, because selectors match elements, not pseudo-elements. What you're really trying to do in selector nomenclature is to style the `::after` pseudo-element of a `div` whose last child is a `p` element (in which case the `::after` box immediately follows the `p` box in the formatting tree):

```
<div>
    <p>hello world</p>
    div::after <!-- Blue border -->
</div>
<div>
    <h4>hello world</h4>
    div::after <!-- Red border -->
</div>
```

And you can't do that, because there is no parent selector.

I imagine something like `div:has(> p:last-child)::after` from Selectors 4 will work, but it depends on whether `:has()` makes it into CSS in the first place. The only other good option is to figure out which of these `div` elements has a `p` as their last child and assign them a special class name.

See also:

- [Can I target a :before or :after pseudo-element with a sibling combinator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735267/can-i-target-an-after-pseudo-element-with-a-sibling-combinator)
- [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: A spot-on interpretation of my question, and a thorough, helpful response; thank you.  I would interested to know how much steam the :has selector has gathered... I've run into several issues recently that it would solve.

Comment: @anthony: Hardly any traction at all last I heard :(