# CSS selecting input with parent span :before pseudo

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

Basically, what I want to do is display the `:before` of the parent span when the input is focused. This is my code.
HTML:

```
<span>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Some text here" />
  <p>Error will be shown here.</p>
</span>
```

And CSS:

```
input[type=text]:focus + span:before{
   display: inline-block;
   position: absolute;
   content: "";
   width: 200px;
   height: 30px;
   background-color: #000;
   border: 1px solid #f00;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
}
```

But this won't work. The `:before` is never displayed. Maybe there is something I'm not doing right. Any help will be appreciated.

This question is not a duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), in that I'm not trying to select the parent. I'm selecting the `:before` of the parent. Doing something like `span > input:focus` works but `span:before > input:focus` does not work.

Comment: As indicated you can't select a parent container from the children. Also, the HTML is invalid. A `span` cannot contain a `p` tag.

Comment: A parent can be selected from children

Comment: No, I'm afraid...it can't. ...and you **are** try to select the parent. The pseudo-element is still part of the parent.

Comment: More suitable duplicate perhaps? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735267/can-i-target-an-after-pseudo-element-with-a-sibling-combinator