# Are :before :after siblings?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

The purpose of the question is to investigate the possibility of doings something like:

```css
.element:before {
  content: 'before';
  color: orange;
}

.element:after {
  content: 'after';
  color: green;
}

.element:after:hover + .element:before {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='element'>&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pseudo-elements cannot be targeted by sibling combinators because [sibling combinators only represent *element* siblings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735267/can-i-target-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-with-a-sibling-combinator/7748876#7748876), not pseudo-element siblings.

So, although the boxes generated by `::before` and `::after` are siblings of one another in terms of layout, for the purposes of sibling combinators they are not.

It is not possible to write a selector styling an element's `::before` pseudo-element when its `::after` pseudo-element is hovered. (For that matter, `::after:hover` is not valid outside of Selectors 4 either, and no implementations exist.) There are [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478336/only-detect-click-event-on-pseudo-element) that make use of things like `pointer-events` but there is nothing that is guaranteed to work on all browsers.