# CSS not working for checkbox list

Tags: css, material-design

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after{
                border: 2px solid red;
                background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="cb1" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
        <label for="cb1">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="cb2" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
        <label for="cb2">Option 2</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="cb3" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
    <label for="cb3">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

I have a list of checkboxes

```
<div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="cb1" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
        <label for="cb1">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="cb2" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
        <label for="cb2">Option 2</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="cb3" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
    <label for="cb3">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

I use the following CSS to change the color of the check boxes when checked:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after{
                border: 2px solid red;
                background-color: red;
        }
```

that does not work. Interestingly, the same CSS:

```
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:after{
                border: 2px solid red;
                background-color: red;
        }
```

works for radiobutton list.

I want something like that:

[image]
  https://d2d3qesrx8xj6s.cloudfront.net/img/screenshots/68b1d126c5b51eb4267aed2e5fd751db1c72aa1b.jpeg

Comment: Are you sure that CSS works for radio inputs? Because you can't actually use sibling selectors and pseudo-elements together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I target a :before or :after pseudo-element with a sibling combinator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735267/can-i-target-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-with-a-sibling-combinator)

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish by using `:after` with the `label`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that worked for me. I added a class to each checkbox - `class="filled-in"` and changed my css:

```
input[type="checkbox"].filled-in:checked + label:after{
    border: 2px solid red;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's the entirety of your code it won't work as is. You'll need to give the `:after` psuedo element some additional properties. Namely `content: "";`

**Update** - In a comment you mentioned you just want to add a border to the checkbox. To do that use `outline`. Like this:

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  outline: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input id="cb1" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
  <label for="cb1">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input id="cb2" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
  <label for="cb2">Option 2</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
  <input id="cb3" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
  <label for="cb3">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not make any difference, still the same

Comment: What browser/OS combo are you using?

Comment: I am using Chrome on Windows 7. Also I am using material design framework

Comment: I added a sample image in my question

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any purpose in the code you posted for the `:after` - there is nothing after your label to highlight, so I'm not sure why you are trying to style it.

If you remove it from your rule, the CSS highlights the label in red. I think this is what you are trying to do?

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
     border: 2px solid red;
     background-color: red;
}
```

**Working example:**

```css
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label{
                border: 2px solid red;
                background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="cb1" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
        <label for="cb1">Option 1</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
        <input id="cb2" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
        <label for="cb2">Option 2</label>
</div>

<div class="input-field col s12">
    <input id="cb3" name="testCheck" type="checkbox" required>
    <label for="cb3">Option 3</label>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is I just want to highlight the checkbox itself, not the label