# CSS: Select after pseudo element when preceeded by some selector

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have a list similar to:

```
<ul class="products">
    <li class="product-category">
    <li class="product-category">
    <li class="product">
    <li class="product">
</ul>
```

If there is at least one `li.product-category` in the list, I need a selector to target `ul::after`. In other words I want to select `ul::after` when preceeded by a `li.product-category`.

My failed attempts:

```
li.product-category ~ ul::after {}
li.product-category ~ ::after {}
ul > li.product-category ~ ::after {}
ul > li.product-category ~ :scope::after {}
```

Comment: you cannot do this with CSS (at least for now)

Comment: ＠TermaniAfif is it talking about to select the pseudo element after the first ```.product-category```?

Comment: You're effectively looking for the [`:has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has) pseudo-class, which is (currently) unavailable in any browser identified by MDN (previous link) or [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/css-has). Until such a time as that is implemented in browsers you'd need to use JavaScript.

Comment: See also [Can I target a :before or :after pseudo-element with a sibling combinator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735267/can-i-target-a-before-or-after-pseudo-element-with-a-sibling-combinator)